# MathJax - how to render equations in “title” atribute?

Tags: mathjax, rendering

Is it possible to force MathJax to render equations that are in title attribute of img or other element  ?

e.g.

```
<img src="xx.png title =" $$ \frac {3}{4}} $$ ">
```

now it don't work. Page return only plain text.

Comment: Questions about MathJaX are better asked on specific MathJaX support sites (see the main mathjax page for more details).  Although MathJaX tries to emulate bits of TeX, it is not built on top of TeX and so expertise in TeX does not translate to expertise in MathJaX; thus questions about MathJaX tend not to be "on topic" for this site.